# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|<\infty \implies \exists N$ such that $\sum_{i=N}^ \infty |a_i|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|<\infty \implies \exists m$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=m}^ \infty |a_i|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Proof) Let $S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} |a_k|$. Since $S_n$ converges, it is Cauchy, so

for any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N$ such that $|S_n-S_m|=\left|\displaystyle\sum_{k=m+1}^n|a_k|\right|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m>N$.

Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ of both sides, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}|a_k|<\epsilon$.

I am wondering if this proof is correct.

Comment: Use the Cauchy condition with $\epsilon/2$ and you are done! This way you get $\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty |a_k|\leq \epsilon/2<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your statement is not true. You should move the "for all $\epsilon>0$" part to right after "$\Rightarrow$".

> $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|<\infty \implies \forall\epsilon>0\ \exists N$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=N}^ \infty |a_i|<\epsilon$

In your proof, when taking the limit $n\to\infty$, you should conclude that
$$
\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty |a_k|\le \epsilon\tag{1}
$$
not the strict inequality.

But since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, you can eventually replace $\le$ with the $<$. To be precise, the following two statements are equivalent

- for every $\epsilon>0$, $A\le \epsilon$;
- for every $\epsilon>0$, $A<\epsilon$.